# paste image on another image in android

Tags: android

i want to display an image in an ImageView on an already existing image captured by device camera and then modify that first image as user wanted like zoom ,rotate and then on button click want to put that view intact ...means that image should be pasted on that camera captured image on button click ...now all i want is to know that how will i paste that image on button click??

```
public class Camera_finalActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  view.setOnTouchListener(this);

  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,100);

  }   

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
         Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
         int width = b.getWidth();
         final int height = b.getHeight();
         img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         img1.setImageBitmap(b);

     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

//want some code here to paste the image on camera captured image....

        }
    });

}
//here was the code to zoom and rotate the image......

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it ...

jst put the following code in ur button click

```
                 @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            view.setOnTouchListener(null); 
                       }
```

and then take a screenshot to save the image...